# jQuery Code in included PHP pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, include, slidetoggle

I am currently encountering a problem with PHP and jQuery.

I have build a website like this:

header.php - this is where all the css and js files are loaded. 
index.php - main page.
sidemenu.php - this is the side menu, which is included in index.php

Inside sidemenu.php I have this JS code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".more").live('click', function(){
        $(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle(500); });
    });
    </script>
```

Which should get the .more to slideToggle:

```
<div class="twocol" id="side-menu">

    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Dashboard</li>     
        <li class="more"><a href="#">Security Settings</a> <img src="images/dropdown-menu.png" align="right"></li>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>Blacklistings</li>
                <li>New Membership Package</li>  
            </ul>                        
        <li class="more"><a href="memberships.php">Memberships</a> <img src="images/dropdown-menu.png" align="right"></li>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>New Membership</li>
                <li>New Membership Package</li>  
            </ul>         
        <li>Forums</li>  
        <li>Help Desk</li>
        <li class="help">Documentation</li>    
    </ul>   

</div><!-- END 2col -->
```

Yet, nothing happens when I click the .more.

Weird enough, if I just make a page with the source code of the three pages above, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the resulting source code in the browser when you load the page in the "includes" version? Also, why "function ($)"?

Comment: Then there must be something wrong in the way you generate the page from PHP, check the source code.

Comment: I did check the source code. No errors.

Comment: live() is deprecated, use on() instead :)

Furthermore, I don't understand how your page is setup. You have index.php, which includes header.php, sidemenu.php and main.php?

Comment: Without more information this question is impossible to answer. Have you generated a `diff` of the PHP-generated page and the static page to make absolutely sure that there are no differences? If not, that should be your next step. Another thing you could check out is whether there's a difference in the HTTP headers between the two versions (i.e. does the PHP-version set headers the static page doesn't have?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wich version of jQuery are you using? I found this on the jQuery website:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You should replace :</strike>

```
$(this).next(".submenu").slideToggle(500);
```

By

```
$(this).children(".submenu").slideToggle(500);
```

(Next calls the following tag in the same level)

**Edit :**

I'm a little blind, I didn't see that you closed the tag with class `.more` before opening the `<ul>` tag with your submenu. However, that showed me another problem: you are putting `<li>` elements in the same level as `<ul>` elements inside the same tag.